# Does vacuum energy have an average temperature of 0° Kelvin?

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, vacuum

[Vacuum energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_energy) has [zero-point energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy). Does this imply that vacuum energy [has] an average temperature of 0° Kelvin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to define temperature, but a simple way to understand it is that some medium has a temperature greater than zero if heat can flow from that medium to a colder medium.

But even though the vacuum does indeed have a zero point energy, that energy is still the lowest energy state possible. So there is nothing *colder* than the vacuum where the energy can flow, and that means the temperature of the vacuum is zero despite the zero point energy.

We get a similar, and simpler, phenomenon with liquid helium. When you cool helium down to absolute zero it still has a vibrational zero point energy, so even at absolute zero its energy isn't zero. In fact that zero point energy is great enough to keep helium a liquid even at absolute zero. Despite this the temperature is zero simply because the zero point vibrational energy in the helium can't flow anywhere colder.